# Creating functions with logical comparatives as input R

Tags: r, function, logical-operators

I've got several sequential comparative evaluations to conduct with two variables in R in order to check for concordance.

In this example, say I have a boolean ANES_6 and a numeric ANES. The boolean is 1 if the patient had anesthesia for more than 6 hours, 0 else. The numeric value is the time the patient was under anesthesia.

I'm looking to write a function which can replace multiple copy-pastes of the following:

```
data %>% select(ANES_6, ANES) %>% 
          filter(ANES_6 == 1 & ANES < 6)) %>% 
          tally()

data %>% select(ANES_6, ANES) %>% 
          filter(ANES_6 == 0 & ANES >= 6)) %>% 
          tally()

data %>% select(ANES_6, ANES) %>% 
              filter(ANES_6 == 1 & ANES >= 6)) %>% 
              tally()

data %>% select(ANES_6, ANES) %>% 
              filter(ANES_6 == 0 & ANES >= 6)) %>% 
              tally()
```

I could create the following function (non-exhaustive of all cases shown above):

```
my_func <- function(x, y) {
 if (x == "gt" & y == 1) {
      data %>% select(ANES_6, AnaestheticTime_hours_) %>% 
           filter(ANES >= 6 & ANES_6 == 1) %>% 
           tally()
 } else if (x == "lt" & y == 0 ) {
      data %>% select(ANES_6, AnaestheticTime_hours_) %>% 
           filter(ANES < 6 & ANES_6 != 1) %>% 
           tally()
 }}
```

which takes x and y as input, with values for x being c('lt', 'gt'), and y being c(0, 1), in order to evaluate all possible condition. However, this would entail writing more code, and not less.

Is there a way to input logical comparisons in the function such that the following works:

```
my_func <- function(x, y) {
          data %>% select(ANES_6, ANES) %>% 
               filter(ANES x 6 & ANES_6 == y) 
     }
```

with `x` replaced by `>=`, `<`, etc, in the input of the function. Currently, this does not work, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping.  The question should normally include reproducible test data but I have provided it this time.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(ANES_6 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), ANES = 5:6) # test data
data %>%
  group_by(ANES_6, ANES >= 6) %>%
  tally %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  ANES_6 `ANES >= 6`     n
   <dbl> <lgl>       <int>
1     0. FALSE           1
2     0. TRUE            1
3     1. FALSE           1
4     1. TRUE            1
```